# How to modify subcolumn names in a nested array in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I tried to modify a JSON source's attribute names, where those attributes(subcolumns) are in a nested array.

Source JSON:

```
[
    {
        "brand": "Toyota",
        "models": [
            { "name": "Corolla", "year": 2020 },
            { "name": "Yaris", "year": 2021}
        ]
    },
    {
        "brand": "BMW",
        "models": [
            { "name": "X5", "year": 2020 },
            { "name": "X6", "year": 2023 }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "carBrand": "Toyota",
        "models": [
            { "modelName": "Corolla", "marketingYear": 2020 },
            { "modelName": "Yaris", "marketingYear": 2021 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "carBrand": "BMW",
        "models": [
            { "modelName": "X5", "marketingYear": 2020 },
            { "modelName": "X6", "marketingYear": 2023 }
        ]
    }
]
```

From pipeline / dataflow, I used Derived Columns:
`models = @(modelName=models.name, marketingYear=models.year)`

It did create 'modelName' and 'marketingYear', whereas both became **array format** and collected all items result into one which is not what I need.

```
{"brand":"Toyota","models":{"modelName":["Corolla","Yaris"],"marketingYear":[2020,2021]}}
{"brand":"BMW","models":{"modelName":["X5","X6"],"marketingYear":[2020,2023]}}
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In order to rename the columns in the complex array data, you can flatten the data and rename and then aggregate the data. Below is the approach
- Take the flatten activity and Unroll by `models[]` value. While mapping the input and output columns , rename the column as required. Check the below screenshot.

[image]

- Then take the Aggregate transformation to aggregate the data back to original Json form.

```
group by: carBrand
Aggregates: model=collect(@(modelName=modelName, marketingYear=marketingYear))
```

[image]

**Output**

```
{"carBrand":"BMW","models":[{"modelName":"X5","marketingYear":2020},{"modelName":"X6","marketingYear":2023}]}
{"carBrand":"Toyota","models":[{"modelName":"Corolla","marketingYear":2020},{"modelName":"Yaris","marketingYear":2021}]}
```